# How do monster cohorts work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The bestiary says they "gain a key class level," when they level up.  Does this mean they take their first level or appropriate cohort level in say, fighter?

So, in example;

If I'm level 10, then my max cohort class level is 8 according to the CRB.

If I get a monster cohort and then we both level up (so I go to 11 bringing my max cohort level up to 9), will my monster cohort have the level up bonuses of a level 1 fighter or a level 9 fighter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cohort starting level + class levels needs to be less than or equal to your max cohort level. Each time your cohort levels it gains the bonuses of 1 class level.

Examples:

Both assume your max cohort level is 9.

If you have a Griffon cohort (starts as level 8 cohort) and it gains a level, you could give it 1 level of fighter.

If you had a Ghoul cohort (starts at level 5) it could level up 4 times, each time it could get 1 new level of fighter. At level 9 it would have the class bonuses as if it were a 4th level fighter.